# Using CURLOPT_CONNECT_TO with an IPv6 address

Tags: libcurl, ipv6

I am attempting to use curl's CURLOPT_CONNECT_TO option to connect to a specific address (rather than the result of the DNS lookup of the host part of the url):

```
CURL * r_curl = NULL;
struct curl_slist * r_connect = NULL;
char connectStr[128];

if (af == AF_INET) {
    sprintf(connectStr, "::%s:", ipAddrString);
} else if (af == AF_INET6) {
    /* in [] per https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_CONNECT_TO.html */
    sprintf(connectStr, "::[%s]:", ipAddrString);
}
fprintf(stderr, "DEBUG: connect '%s', url %s\n", connectStr, url);

r_curl = curl_easy_init();
    ...
r_connect = curl_slist_append(r_connect, connectStr);
curl_easy_setopt(r_curl, CURLOPT_CONNECT_TO, r_connect);
curl_easy_setopt(r_curl, CURLOPT_URL, url);
curl_easy_perform(r_curl);
```

When `af` is AF_INET and `ipAddrSring` is an IPv4 address this works perfectly.  When `af` is AF_INET6 and `ipAddrSring` is an IPv6 address, curl looks like it is trying to do a DNS host lookup on the IPv6 address:

> DEBUG: connect '::129.186.23.166:', url http://www.iastate.edu/
>   * Connecting to hostname: 129.186.23.166
>   *   Trying 129.186.23.166...
>   * TCP_NODELAY set
>   * Connected to 129.186.23.166 (129.186.23.166) port 80 (#0)

vs

> DEBUG: connect '::[2610:130:101:104::2]:', url http://www.iastate.edu/
>   * Connecting to hostname: 2610:130:101:104::2
>   * Could not resolve host: 2610:130:101:104::2

What I am doing wrong here?

(Curl is version 7.56.1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was a bug in libcurl (before 7.58.0) which made it take IPv6 addresses and attempt to use them for CURLOPT_CONNECT_TO, even if it was built without support for IPv6!

This was addressed in curl 7.58.0 and from then on it makes libcurl return an error if this is attempted!

Answer (score 0):

Answer: Curl Library was built w/o IPv6 support.

I'm thinking that maybe that should result in a more meaningful error message.

Comment: Bug report submitted.